# Unsupervised clustering of factors and strings

Tags: r, text, cluster-analysis, tm, hierarchical

I have a dataset with factors and a few free form fields (user entered data). I am trying to cluster this dataset using both k-means and hierarchical clustering. The data looks like below:

```
prod_name   prod_detail_1   company model   product_problem_description
1   motor pump  1   123A    broken 
1   calculator  2   WE4     battery not working
2   motor pump  3   564     display broken
3   refrigerator3   12E     regular inspection
4   calculator  4   453E    regular inspection
5   motor pump  1   123A    pump will not turn on
```

I have used the "tm" package to clean and create a document term matrix for the "product_problem_description" considering each entry as one document. (The problem descriptions I have written above are very simple, but are more complicated in the actual data and cannot be considered as factors)

```
prob_desc_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(data$product_problem_description))
removeNumPunct <- function(x) gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]]*", "", x)
prob_desc_corpus <- tm_map(prob_desc_corpus,     content_transformer(removeNumPunct))
prob_desc_matrix <- DocumentTermMatrix(prob_desc_corpus, 
                                   control=list(
                                     minWordLength=2,
                                     stopwords = TRUE,
                                     stripWhitespace = TRUE,
                                     stemming = TRUE))
```

I then used cbind to attach columns 1 through 4 to this document term matrix.

```
full_data <- cbind(data$prod_name, data$detail_1, data$company, data$model,        as.data.frame(as.matrix(prob_desc_matrix)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I am using this dataset for hierarchical clustering purposes.

```
distances= dist(full_data, method = "euclidean") 
hc <- hclust(distances, method = "ward.D") 
plot(hc)
```

Is this a valid approach for clustering a dataset like above? 
This is my first time posting a question, so apologies if the question is a little vague.